# Element in td with position:relative overlaps on another position:fixed element

Tags: html, css

I have a mystery to solve: on my web page there's a fixed top panel **div** (similar to gmail's top panel). Below, I have a table with several cells, and the last cell is defined like this:

```
<td class="col-time">
    <div title="średnie: 180, maksymalne: 186, minimalne: 142" class="hr-avg">
        <span>180 (89%) </span>/ <span class="hr-max">186 (92%) </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

The **hr-avg** applies **position:relative** style.

Issue is: when scrolling, table is hidden under that top panel (panel's opacity is 1). But what suprises me is that cell defined with **position:relative** style doesn't hide under panel. Panel & cell's content overlap (it gives the effect like top panel has opacity only for that cell). Could somebody explain that behaviour?

Thanks,Pawel

Comment: can you please share the code... will be easy for SO ppl to understand then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be fixed by giving your top panel div a `z-index` which is higher than anything that has to be below it.

The reason this only occurs with the `hr-avg` is because it's (probably) the only element apart from the top panel that has a `position` other than `static`. And then because it appears after the top panel in your HTML it will be stacked on top of it by default (since they both have no `z-index`).

Setting the `z-index` of the top panel to a high number like `99999` should fix your problem (the high number is so you can still stack things in your content without going above the top panel).

Comment: thx! Z-index resolved the issue. However, does it mean that setting position:relative affects element's position in "stack"?

Comment: @dragonfly, elements with `position:static;` (the default) are not included in the 'stack'. They will always be below any element that has a `position` of `relative`, `absolute` etc. When multiple elements are positioned dynamically, the order will be based off `z-index`, and if no z-index is specified (or they are the same) they will be ordered by DOM position.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that ? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp - I found this "...The content of relatively positioned elements can be moved and overlap other elements, but the reserved space for the element is still preserved in the normal flow...", but it not exactly what you ment ?

Comment: @dragonfly, the part you quoted is simply talking about the fact that if you move around a relatively positioned element by using css attributes such as `top` and `left` that their original position is what is used to determine the position of other elements. This has nothing to do with `z-index`.